# Android rx Java misunderstanding of SwitchMap, getting unexpected results

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I've been playing around with project that's like a debate between 2 people. Viewers can send gifts to the person they like. Either the host or guest get a gift and fun animations play and once the animation is complete the next gift can play.

I have the following RX java code to complete that action. Gifts goto either the Host or the Guest and queue up. Then I can trigger the valve to show the next gift, aka on animation ends, But im getting unexpected results and I don't know why.

```
//Begin app code
    val giftValveSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(true)                                                           
    val valve = giftValveSubject                                                                                         
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)                                                                         
        .filter { it }                                                                                                   
    val guestGiftSubject = PublishSubject.create<Gift>()
    val hostGiftSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<Gift>()                                                                 
    val currentGuestId: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create()                                                 
    val allGuestGiftsByRecipient: Observable<GroupedObservable<String, Gift>> = guestGiftSubject.groupBy { it.recipient }
    val guestGifts =                                                                                                     
        currentGuestId                                                                                                   
            .switchMap { guestId ->                                                                                      
                if (guestId.isEmpty())                                                                                   
                    Observable.never()                                                                                   
                else {                                                                                                   
                    allGuestGiftsByRecipient                                                                             
                        .filter { it.key == guestId }                                                                    
                        .switchMap { it }                                                                                
                }                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                            
    val gifts =                                                                                                          
        hostGiftSubject.mergeWith(guestGifts).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)                                    
            .concatMap { gift ->                                                                                         
                valve                                                                                                    
                    .doOnNext { giftValveSubject.onNext(false) }                                                         
                    .take(1)                                                                                             
                    .map { gift }                                                                                        
            }  
//End App Code

//Begin tests                                                                                                          
    // Host starts. Initially, nothing happens nothing in the queues                                                                  
    val o = gifts.test()                                                                                                 
    //Guest joins the room                                                                                                      
    currentGuestId.onNext("guest")                                                                                       

    //Send 1 gift                                                                                                        
    guestGiftSubject.onNext(Gift("guest", "gg1"))                                                                        
    //Valve is open by default so gg1 is emitted                                                                         
    System.out.println("1. values: " + o.valueCount() + " " + o.values().toString())                                     
    //Valve is now closed                                                                                                
    //Add another guest gift. O is unchanged                                                                             
    guestGiftSubject.onNext(Gift("guest", "gg2"))                                                                        
    System.out.println("2. values: " + o.valueCount() + " " + o.values().toString())                                     
    //Host gets a gift. Valve is closed. O is unchanged                                                                  
    hostGiftSubject.onNext(Gift("host", "g1"))                                                                           
    System.out.println("3. values: " + o.valueCount() + " " + o.values().toString())                                     
    // Guest leaves: Expect switchmap to clear all guest gifts.                                                          
    currentGuestId.onNext("")                                                                                            
    //Host gift should be only one pending                                                                               
    giftValveSubject.onNext(true)                                                                                        
    //Valve is open. next gift is emitted                                                                                
    //Expected result 4. values: 2 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1), Gift(recipient=host, gift=g1)]                      
    System.out.println("4. values: " + o.valueCount() + " " + o.values().toString())    
//End Tests
```

output

```
1.values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
2.values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
3.values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
4.values: 2 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1), Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg2)]
```

Notice item 4. Why am I getting a guest value for item 2? When the guest left, the switchmap should have set guestGifts to Observable.empty() so when the valve was open the next gift should have been for the host.

Answer (score 0):

At first, i check the switch map but it actually works as it should be. The culprit here is actually concatMap operator that are used when `gifts` creation.

The reason behind this because `concatMap` operator keep all of the items emitted by the first Observable being emitted before any of the items emitted by the second Observable (and so forth, if there are more than two)`.

To make it easier to see, i've create log extension and modified your code here:

```
    // extension log
    private fun <T> Flowable<T>.log(tag: String = ""): Flowable<T> {
        return this
                .doOnSubscribe { println("$tag onSubscribe $this") }
                .doOnNext { println("$tag onNext $it") }
                .doOnError { println("$tag onError $it") }
                .doOnComplete { println("$tag onComplete $this") }
    }

... rest of your code
 val gifts =
                hostGiftSubject.mergeWith(guestGifts).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                        .log("source-gift")
                        .concatMap { gift ->
                            //                            println("$gift")
                            valve
                                    .doOnNext { giftValveSubject.onNext(false) }
                                    .take(1)
                                    .map { gift }
                                    .log("output-gift")
                        }
```

and you will see log each gift was sent:

```
source-gift onSubscribe io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnBackpressureBuffer@6ebc05a6
source-gift onNext Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)
output-gift onSubscribe io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap@6c49835d
output-gift onNext Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)
output-gift onComplete io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap@6c49835d
1. values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
source-gift onNext Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg2)
output-gift onSubscribe io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap@1e6d1014
2. values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
source-gift onNext Gift(recipient=host, gift=g1)
3. values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
output-gift onNext Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg2)
output-gift onComplete io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap@1e6d1014
output-gift onSubscribe io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap@1c3a4799
4. values: 2 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1), Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg2)]
```

You could see that your code actually never emit gift for host inside `concatMap`. It because it still keeping the subscription for Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg2).

I'm not wholly understand logic behind your code, so i'm not able to come up with how it should be.

I try tinkering little bit with replacing `concatMap` with `switchMap` and it produces log that you (may) want:

```
1. values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
2. values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
3. values: 1 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1)]
4. values: 2 [Gift(recipient=guest, gift=gg1), Gift(recipient=host, gift=g1)]
```

But, i'm not sure if the reason behind this result is same with your expectation.